# Is it possible to receive information from share action in a shortcut?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

For example, I want to have a shortcut "get meta info from image" like this:

1. I open Photos on my iPad.
2. I Select an image and click the Share button.
3. I Select  "get meta info from image" shortcut in the popup menu.
4. The shortcut runs and it can receive the image which I selected.
5. The shortcut popup a dialog that has meta text information (e.g. name, size, ...).

I stuck in step 4.

How to make a shortcut receive information from share action?

Or is it possible to receive information from share action in a shortcut?

Thanks.

Edit:

Add screenshot of the shortcut I have so far

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Shortcut you have so far?

Comment: @nohillside I have upload a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it could.

I asked a question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/fgh1dk/is_it_possible_to_receive_information_from_share/) and got an good answer.

Thanks StewieOi.

This is the final solution, if anyone encounters the same problem as me, you can refer: https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/eb687b48bd1444e9b3f9169a8d1f1084